# How can I store the value of the arrays to an individual variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this code of mine wherein before I store the values of my array, they are first sorted and filtered to the the nearest value of the user input by 5 data points. Here is my code:

[image: 1]

I tried storing them from the console.log(findClosest) command but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Answer (score -3):

It looks like the findClosest function is defined as an arrow function and is not returning a value. Arrow functions implicitly return the value of the expression on the right side of the =>, so you will need to explicitly return the value you want to store in the closest variable.

```html
const findClosest = (arr, num) => {
  return arr.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a - num) - Math.abs(b - num)).filter((a, i) => i < 5);
}
```

Comment: `findClosest` has a return value in the screenshot `return array.sort(..).slice(..).sort(..)`